# jazzyviewpager scaled flip

Tags: android, animation, flip

Hey guys (for those of you, who are using Jazzyviewpager). 
I am using Horizontal flip Animation. To me, animation doesn't seem perfect because the edges of the view are coming out of the screen while rotating it.
Anyway, what I am trying to do is to scale the view while rotating it - make it smaller during the rotation.
To me It seems, that while rotating the view scale doesn't work at all. When I don't use rotation scale is working correctly. Please help !
Here is my code:

```
if (mState != State.IDLE) {
        if (left != null) {
            manageLayer(left, true);
            mRot = -180.0f * positionOffset;

            if (mRot < -90.0f) {
                left.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            } else {
                if (left.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE)
                    left.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mTrans = positionOffsetPixels;
                mScale = ZOOM_MAX + (1-ZOOM_MAX)*(1-positionOffset);

                ViewHelper.setPivotX(left, left.getMeasuredWidth()*0.5f);
                ViewHelper.setPivotY(left, left.getMeasuredHeight()*0.5f);
                ViewHelper.setScaleX(left, mScale);
                ViewHelper.setScaleY(left, mScale);
                ViewHelper.setTranslationX(left, mTrans);
                ViewHelper.setRotationY(left, mRot);
            }
        }

        if (right != null) {
            manageLayer(right, true);
            mRot = 180.0f * (1-positionOffset);

            if (mRot > 90.0f) {
                right.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            } else {
                if (right.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE)
                    right.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mTrans = -getWidth()-getPageMargin()+positionOffsetPixels;
                mScale = ZOOM_MAX + (1-ZOOM_MAX)*positionOffset;

                ViewHelper.setPivotX(right, right.getMeasuredWidth()*0.5f);
                ViewHelper.setPivotY(right, right.getMeasuredHeight()*0.5f);
                ViewHelper.setScaleX(right, mScale);
                ViewHelper.setScaleY(right, mScale);
                ViewHelper.setTranslationX(right, mTrans);
                ViewHelper.setRotationY(right, mRot);
            }
        }
    }
```